# Difficulty setting up iptables

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, troubleshooting

I'm very new to *nix operating systems, and I'm having some trouble which I believe is because of misconfiguration of the iptables firewall.

My server has SSH running on port 22, and server software running on TCP port 25565. SSH and the server software respond appropriately to connections made from inside the network (that is, connections made using the server's local address, 10.0.0.xx). However, if I attempt to access them from outside the network or using the router's external IP address, they do not respond.

The router is configured to forward those ports to the server; I very much doubt there is an error there.

After researching iptables, I tried a few guides, but I am not seeing any results.

The output of iptables -L is as such:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27015
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

An nmap scan from inside the network reports that port 22 and 25565 are open, and that ports 80 and 2705 (another server software that I am not running at the moment) are closed. Running nmap with the router's external IP returns no useful results; I believe the router is detecting the scan attempt and refusing to respond.

The server is running Debian in text-only mode.

Does anyone see what the problem is, or have troubleshooting steps to suggest?

In response to comments:

netstat -tpln gives the following (among other things); I assume this is good, though the difference between tcp and tcp6 escapes me.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::25565                :::*                    LISTEN      3092/java
```

Hosts.deny is devoid of entries.

However, /var/auth.log has some... *interesting* contents. Is it normal for people to start trying to bruteforce my root password the very minute SSH is exposed?

But yes, a perusal of the logs seems to suggest that I'm the only person who cannot SSH into my server.

Comment: `state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` should be the first rule not the last. And you should use `--ctstate` instead. But that's just am optimization, not the solution to your problem. Run tcpdump on the external interface and try to connecto to it, e.g. `tcpdump -i eth0 -n tcp port 22`. That shows you whether packets arrive at the host and whether the host tries to answer (over this interface).

Comment: Is other program on port 25565 using `tcp` protocol? Try run `netstat -tpln`, is this program in the listing?

Comment: Is there anything on /etc/hosts.deny. What does /var/log/auth.log say when you try ssh from outside? Also try tcpdump -i eth0 -nn same time as Giovanni has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

iptables is one of the worst (best?) examples of "let's just export the raw kernel tables and let the admin make sense of it" design.

[Uncomplicated Firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall) will handle the common cases like you describe and leave you with you sanity. It's just a wrapper around iptables, but one that speaks in task structure not kernel structures.

Comment: Debian is usually using `ufw` package... But doing firewall with `any` package without understanding basics is way to the hell.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your iptables and set default policy to `ACCEPT`, if you can connect your problem is with your iptables rules otherwise your router is buggy.

About the entries in your auth.log file, there's several blocklist for known-bot-nets that are most likely trying to break your configuration (or is just you with your testing), install `openssh-blacklist-extra` to provide additional protection (it should be installed along with sshd, but a quick check could help). Also, should be good idea `fail2ban` too.

Answer (score 1):

> But yes, a perusal of the logs seems to suggest that I'm the only
>   person who cannot SSH into my server.

That rings a bell ... are you trying to connect to your public IP from the *internal* network? That's not likely to work. You must test your access from the internet side of the router, e.g. from a VPS or a 3G mobile. Just a thought...

Comment: I'll try that then. Connecting to the public IP from inside has never caused problems for me before, that's usually how I test these things, but I'll take your word for it. I did try it from another network just to be sure before, but that was a library and might have had the relevant ports blocked.

Comment: Had someone else try accessing the server, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `tcpdump -i eth0 -nn` to see what's going on on the wire. There should be connection attempts and responses like this:

  ```
  14:20:38.482053 IP 172.31.170.1.42111 > 172.31.170.102.22: Flags [S], seq ...
  14:20:38.482095 IP 172.31.170.102.22 > 172.31.170.1.42111: Flags [S.], seq ...
  ```

  if the response to `[S]` is not `[S.]` but something else like `[R]` or an ICMP packet then there's something wrong.
- Check the routing table: `ip route show` - is there a default route pointing to the router?
- Can the router actually ping the server and vice versa?

Comment: tcpdump reveals that nothing is arriving at the machine when accessed via external address. It would seem that would rule out iptables, since I assume it can see things that would otherwise be blocked (it always says "0 packets dropped by kernel"). The routing table entry for the router is "default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0", which I assume is good. The router is unfortunately not capable of diagnostics; however, it reports that it sees the server, and I assume it is doing so by pinging it.

Comment: @Schilcote - if there is no incoming traffic it most likely means the router isn't forwarding the packets from outside to your server. There may be a few separate knobs to turn it on - general forwarding enable, specific rules, NAT settings, etc. The exact settings are very much specific to each router model.

Comment: @Schilcote also, did you tried `nmap -p 22 external_ip`? Check your router firewall/security/intrusion detection rules too, they usually mess with the routing.

Answer (score 0):

While you can configure `iptables` by hand, it is much more reliable to use a tool to build the firewall according you your requirements.   I find [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) to be a well documented and easy to use tool.  It is available as a package.  If you require IPv6, there is also a Shorewal6 package.  There are example configuration for a number of configurations that make a good starting point.

The `ucf` package can also be used to build a rule set.

Either will set up some standard rules that you may miss when rolling your own firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Your iptables rule set is permitting access to TCP port 22 where you have your SSH daemon running. If you cannot reach it from the Internet it's because of 1) the router/firewall is blocking access or 2) the port forward is incorrectly setup or 3) the SSH daemon is not listening on the correct interface or 4) SSH is configured to reject connections from whatever ranges. A similar logic applies to your server software.

Note: Your related/established rule normally comes on top due to performance and to improve readability of the rule set. Also you might want to split the rule set per interface, it is a lot less error prone that way. You might want to use a firewall wrapper but I find them just as complicated as managing iptables directly.